# What are plugins(Architect) in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, cloud9

While working on Cloud9 and Node JS, I came across this [link](https://github.com/c9/architect), what is a plugin and why is it needed in Node JS? And what is the difference between node modules and plugins?

Comment: This is just some software project. It's not needed for Node.js, nor is it a replacement/alternative for modules.

Comment: Well I have read some slides [here](https://www.slideshare.net/sergimansilla/architecting-large-nodejs-applications-14912706) but unable to grasp the whole idea.
Is it saying that divide larger application in to smaller parts, e.g: login, dashboard, email, messages, logging and etc. And then integrate them in a single Application. (Like a mixture of modular and monolithic application).

Comment: It's something that Cloud9 has developed for their platform. There isn't a general conception of what a plug-in is in Node.js, it's something that this particular project defines for itself.